# Implementing a custom component for a tri state switch with states(enabled, partial, disabled) using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Want to implement something like a switch that has three states, "ENABLED,PENDING,DISABLED" . Can someone help me out to bring up a component like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick function that you can use. It cycles from 0 (DISABLED), to 1 (PARTIAL) and finally 2 (ENABLED) or whatever you want.

```
import React from 'react'

class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            toggleState: 0
        }
    }

    switch = () => {
        this.setState(({toggleState}) => ({toggleState: toggleState % 2 === 0 && toggleState !== 0 ? 0 : toggleState + 1}))
    }    

    render() {
        const {toggleState} = this.state
        // TODO create the MyToggleComponent

        return <React.Fragment>
            <Button onClick={() => this.switch()} />
            <MyToggleComponent toggleState={toggleState} />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a code snippet? It will be really helpful

Comment: see the improved answer here

Answer (score -2):

Yes it can be a slider with 3 state like [0, 1, 2]